AWS Lambda trigger does not execute AWS Step function
I wrote lambda function that is reading message from SQS, decoding and starting Step function.
When I am running it manually in AWS Lambda everything is executed properly so messages are read, decoded and step function is executed. However when I add lambda trigger to SQS then it does not execute my step function at all. I can see in Monitor in AWS Lambda that my function was invoked correctly but it did not exexcute step function. Why is that and how to fix it?
import logging
import boto3
import base64
import json
import os
import ast

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def get_queue_url(queue_name):
    """
    Get the URL of the queue dynamically based on its name.
    """
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
    response = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=queue_name)
    return response['QueueUrl']


def decode_celery_message(body):
    """
    Decode and parse the Celery message.
    """
    decoded_body = base64.b64decode(body).decode('utf-8')
    try:
        parsed_body = json.loads(decoded_body)
        if 'kwargsrepr' in parsed_body['headers']:
            kwargsrepr = parsed_body['headers']['kwargsrepr']
            task_id = parsed_body['headers']['id']
            kwargsrepr_dict = ast.literal_eval(kwargsrepr)
            kwargsrepr_dict['task_id'] = task_id
            return kwargsrepr_dict
        else:
            logger.error("'kwargsrepr' not found in the message headers.")
            return None
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        logger.error("Error decoding JSON: %s", e)
        return None


def start_step_function_execution(parsed_message):
    """
    Start the execution of the Step Function.
    """
    stepfunctions_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    logger.info(f"Starting Step Function execution with input: {parsed_message}")
    stepfunctions_client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn=os.environ['STEP_FUNCTION_ARN'],
        input=json.dumps(parsed_message) 
    )
    logger.info("Step Function execution started successfully.")
    return parsed_message


def display_message_available(event, context):
    queue_name = os.environ["QUEUE_NAME"]  # Queue name
    queue_url = get_queue_url(queue_name)
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

    logger.info(f"Event details: {event}")
    
    all_messages = []  # List to store all decoded messages with commands
    
    while True:
        # Receive messages from the queue for processing
        response = sqs.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
        )
        
        # Check if any messages were received
        if 'Messages' in response:
            for message in response['Messages']:
                body = message['Body']
                receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
                
                # Decode and parse the message, get the command
                parsed_message = decode_celery_message(body)
                if parsed_message:
                    all_messages.append((parsed_message))
                    
                
                # Delete the message from the queue after processing
                sqs.delete_message(
                    QueueUrl=queue_url,
                    ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
                )
                logger.info(f'Message {body} deleted from the {queue_name} after processing.')
                # Start Step Function execution
                start_step_function_execution(parsed_message)
                logger.info(f"Step Function execution started with input: {parsed_message}")
        else:
            logger.info("No more messages available in the queue.")
            break  # Exit the loop if no more messages are available
        

    return all_messages


# This is necessary for Lambda to know what function to invoke
lambda_handler = display_message_available

I've tried to seperate my function just to start execution and that works great but only if I run lambda manually. I've check IAM permissions and I have grated AdministratorAccess to make sure that I have proper permissions. Below is screenshot from my IAM Role.
I'd like to understand why Step function is not executed with Lamda Trigger enabled and how to fix my issue?
enter image description here

Does lambda have access to read from SQS? Do you see an invocation in the lambda, is the message / event printed correctly?

Lambda reads message from SQS properly. I see in logs Event details but I do not see any logs from start_step_function_execution

Wait wait wait, why does your lambda actively read from SQS? That is not at all how lambda should work here. Your lambda should be triggered by SQS, the messages will be in event and you should only process that and only that. No further interaction receiving or deleting messages from SQS. Remove the entire while loop and anything related to sqs.

ok that makes much more sense than my approach. I wrote this script to test it locally but with lambda trigger I can take it from event parameter. Thanks a lot :)

If I understand what you are looking to do, I think EventBridge Pipes is the best solution. This provides a fully managed way to trigger Step Functions state machines from an SQS Queue (in addition to other sources).
You can find a simple example here.
You have a few options for transforming the SQS messages (what you included in your decode_celery_message method). You may be able to just use input transformation for the Step Functions target. You can alternatively use the optional Enrichment capability of Pipes to do that transformation in a Lambda Function (or in a separate State Machine or API hosted in API-Gateway or through an API Destination). I would suggest you start with the input transformation first, but the right choice will depend on your specific needs.
